# Use a ContentPresenter for personnalize a template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contentpresenter

I created a ressourceDictionnary for creating a templateButton.
I would like to be able to change the png image when i use this template, i think i need to use a ContentPresenter, but i don't know why.

Here is my RessourceDictionnary :

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BoutonRessources">
<Button Width="32" Margin="0,0,7,0" Name="tbrClear" ToolTip="Clear" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">

        <Border>

            <Image Source="xRtDiva_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png" Height="18"/>

        <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="BoutonToolbarSelected.png"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Height"  Value="22"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width"  Value="32"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
</Button>
```

So, when i use this Button template, i would like to be able to pass them an other png image to display. For example i would like to replace xRtDiva_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png by MyPicture.png.

How doing this ? With a contentPresenter ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to change the background of the border (this is what your code does now), or you want to change the actual image shown in the Image element?

Comment: Have you considered using DataBinding (`<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}" Height="18"/>
`)?

Comment: I would like to be able to change the " xRtDiva_XWPF_TBR_PREMIER.PNG_IMAGES.png "

Comment: If i use the binding, how use the binding on my main XAML page please ?